# How do divide and round up in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data like this:

```
ID  customer_id rewards_points (target)
1   23796        10               4
2   24196        20               7
3   24197        30              10
4   24198        40              14
5   24199        50              17
```

I want to divide all values under rewards_points column by 3, then round up to the nearest integer. What query can I run to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value

```
SELECT CEILING(theField/3.0) FROM theTable WHERE ...
```

The set the value

```
UPDATE theTable SET theField = CEILING(theField/3.0) WHERE ....;
```

Comment: or CEIL() - if less typing is your thang

Comment: My paranoia extends to making sure I get decimal division and not integer division (not a problem in MySQL, but I've experienced that gotcha in other RDBMS)... I make sure to divide by **`3.0`**.  (*Hey!* Don't judge me, I think my paranoia is a *medical* condition.)

Comment: I used this but it didn't do anything. I want to update the values in the table to be 1/3 current value, then roundedup to the nearest integer. Would this be the correct query?
update table_name set rewards_points = rewards_points / 3; update round(rewards_points) from table_name;

Comment: @spencer7593, it doesn't just serve paranoia, it also serves to indicate to others that may have to look at you code/query that you intended non-integer division.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select rewards_points DIV 3 as result from table;
```

Comment: That won't round up, it is integer division.

Comment: or, `SELECT (rewards DIV 3) + IF((rewards MOD 3)>0,1,0) AS result`... if *more* typing is your thang.